# Ansible 2.7 - mysql_db : ngzip: stdout: Broken pipe\

Tags: ansible

Using the following instructions, fails the restoration of the database. As i read, archived not supports gz files, should i use a bash script?

```
- name: Restore database
        mysql_db:
          name: zabbixdb
          state: import
          target: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-4.0.3/create.sql.gz
        when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'

      - name: Restore database
        mysql_db:
          name: zabbixdb
          state: import
          target: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql/create.sql.gz
        when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
```

result

```
fatal: [192.168.1.215]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "\ngzip: stdout: Broken pipe\n"}
```

Comment: Do those files actually exist? And are they actually gzipped SQL files?

Comment: solved through zcat: shell: zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-4.0.3/create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix

Comment: So you just had the wrong database name in the playbook, then?

Comment: it seems, it's related with the unarchive module and the unsuported files gz

Comment: gz is supported per documentation. "Broken pipe" suggests something consuming the gzip, the mysql command, is what had the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like (as of February 2019, umerged) PR 26504  [Fixes #20196 broken pipe when special chars in mysql password](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/26504).

Try (temporarily) setting the mysql password to something alphanumeric, avoiding special to the shell characters like `!`.

If you continue to get errors, [set the playbook debugger on the problem task:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#playbook-debugger)  `debugger: on_failed`.  Then dump out the mysql command variable, which you can run manually in the shell to find the problem.